# Application/User Settings with Roaming Profiles

Tags: vb.net, settings, roaming-profile

Hi Guys any help would be much appreciated.

We have an application that’s installed at several locations but we are having an issue at one particular site.  In short the application settings (My.) are not being saved after a reboot.  The application is build in VB.Net v3.5 Framework and we are not experiencing any issues elsewhere.

This particular site is using roaming profiles and the network administrator ensures us that the correct permissions are applied to the user account(s) and all application data is being saved to the server.  I’ve asked the network admin to check for the existence of the user settings file user.config in the Application Data directory and he says it doesn’t exist.

In our application we store the connection string to the database in the application settings under the user scope.  If no connection string is present or if one is present and a connection to the database cannot be made then a form is shown asking the user for the database credentials.  Each morning when the users boot the machine and opens the application for the first time they are asked for these credentials but if they close the application and restart it they are not asked for them.  This indicates to us that the settings are being saved but once the pc is rebooted and the application is opened for the first time they are asked for the database credentials.  This seems like the settings are not persisting after a reboot.

Any thoughts/feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if it's Code Access Security preventing the file from being written?

If the sysadmin at trouble site has implemented [group policy folder redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782799%28WS.10%29.aspx), the user's local/roaming profile could be getting stored on a network fileshare. Code Access Security is fairly picky about letting code read/write to/from network resources.

I'm sorry that I don't have more details than this, and I didn't find any sure-fire hits on google, but searching for *"code access security"*, *"fulltrust"* and any network/fileshare keywords you can think of may get you farther.